# how to get the average from an AS column in the select statement

Tags: sql, average

My data looks like this:

```
  DATE  Ticker    us_cls_price   cls_prc 

  05/23  APPL       $400        $401  
  05/24  IBM        $100        $105
  05/25  AMAZ       $350        $355
```

I am using this select statement:

```
SELECT
  date,ticker,us_cls_price,cls_price,cls_prc-us_cls_price AS prc_diff ...
```

I am trying to get the average of the `prc_diff` column.

```
....AS prc_diff, AVG(prc_diff) ...
```

However, I keep getting an error in which it says the `prc_diff` is invalid.

Is there a way to call on a column created by AS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an alias is used it is only available for referencing outside the query (or subquery, as the case may be). Within that query you must repeat the expression entirely, e.g.

```
SELECT ... us_cls_price AS prc_diff, avg(us_cls_price) as avg_us_cls_price ...
```

If you don't want to repeat the expression, you must use a subquery instead:

```
SELECT ... prc_diff, avg(prc_diff) as avg_us_cls_price ...
FROM ( SELECT ... us_cls_price as prc_diff ... )
```